# Avoid checking for nil when accessing subelement

Tags: hash, nullpointerexception, readability

This is maybe a more cosmetic problem, but I find it really annoying as I always end up with some ugly code. And readability is always important, right?

I want to check if a value exists in a hash within a hash. So what I do is this.

```
already_exists_data[:data][:user_id]
```

But that can get me a nullpointer exception if :data is nil and checking :data might give me a nullpointer if already_exists_data is nil. So what I end up with is this:

```
if already_exists_data && already_exists_data[:data] && already_exists_data[:data][:user_id]
    # Do stuff
end
```

Now that's some nasty looking code. Perhaps I should modify the hash to be an object instead. But I keep bumping in to this problem sometimes and was wondering how you guys confront it.

I'm currently coding in Ruby but I've had this problem with multiple other languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I ask my butler to pick up the box of chocolates on the dining room table in Victoria street 34, I ask him just that. I don't want to say: *Go find Victoria Street, and, if you find it, please look for number 34, and if you find it ...*

I can do that because he catches his own errors: if he doesn't find the street he will just return empty-handed.

So you should use a `try` with an empty exception handler. In pseudo-code:

> try {chocolates = streets("Victoria")(34)("dining room")("table")}

In languages (like `ruby`, with some homespun [syntactic sugar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672445/having-a-ruby-block-command-silently-fail-without-a-blank-rescue-block)) where blocks are expressions you might write:

> if try {already_exists_data(data)(user_id)}
>
> > do_stuff

The language itself can also help: in `perl`, `$streets{Victoria}[34]{dining_room}{table}` is undefined when e.g. `$streets` is. Of course, your butler may come home empty-handed for years before you discover that the address is wrong. The `try` block solution - and your `if .. && ....` - have the same drawback: only use them when you really don't care if Victoria Street has a number 34 or not.

Answer (score 1):

**Language-agnostic solution:** do not use nulls. Ever. Enforce this rule across your projects. If you absolutely have to, [wrap them into `Either`/`Optional` which adds explicitness](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-ft13/index.html). Some languages, such as Scala, have the notion of `Optional` already built in.

**Java-specific solution:** if you have to use nulls, annotate method arguments and return values with `@Nullable` and `@Nonnull`. Decent IDEs (such as IntelliJ) are capable of analysing your code and highlighting possible `null` dereferences, if a value is acquired from such a method.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to wrap the hash access with a function call, and do the "dirty" work within the function.  Then your code will be something like (pseudo-code syntax):

```
accessHash(already_exists_data, data, userid)
```

*Note*: you can get fancy with accessing nested hashes based on the number of parameters passed to the wrapper function, so it works in a multiple of situations.